# Create a new row before and after Laravel Job

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I am using same example as on Queues page on Laravel official page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#job-events for AppServiceProvider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessed;
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessing;

use App\Models;
```

[...]

```
    public function boot()
{
    Queue::before(function (JobProcessing $event) {
      echo "start1";
      $theJobs = new TheJobs;
      $theJobs->test = 'hello';
      echo "start";
      $theJobs->save();
      echo "start3";
    });

    Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
      $theJobs = new TheJobs;
      $theJobs->save();
    });
}
```

As you can see before a queue event and after queue event I am trying to create a new row in `TheJobs` table, however `$theJobs->save();` fails.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are there any errors in the log?

Comment: When I am running a queue, the queue just doesn't execute, and the process keeps repeating.

Comment: You might want to use log class instead of plain echoing of text.

Comment: Just updated the question, from the code above, `start1` and `start` are being displayed, the problem is in `$theJobs->save();`

Comment: Why do you echo `start`, `start3` and `start1` (probably debugging purposes)? your running events, so you won't display it in the browser, so you can't debug like that, making it unnecessary and probably another reason why your code isn't working?